# Why does 'sort' seem to sort a field incorrectly based on the presence or absence of a different field?

Tags: sorting, gnu-coreutils

I found some data which seems to behave strangely in 'sort'. When doing a numerical sort on the first field of a csv file, the presence or absence of the 4th column causes the 7th line to be sorted incorrectly.

I'm using GNU sort 8.21 on Slackware64-current.

Data: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2a7beb4871b25ae8f8b3

This works:

```
cut -d , -f 1-3 < weird.csv | sort -t , -k 1n
```

This does not work:

```
cat weird.csv | sort -t , -k 1n
```

The 7th line seems to be  sorted incorrectly.

I can't seem to find any obvious explanation for this behavior. Using 'g' instead of 'n' has the behavior I would expect, but I'm not clear on what the difference is between 'g' and 'n'.

Comment: It works correctly on OS X, but I reproduced it on Linux with GNU sort 8.5.

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com would probably be a better place for the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Sort command does not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867826/the-sort-command-does-not-work-as-expected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong. Detailed explanation provided here: http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=19021

In short, I should have used '-k 1,1n' to specify that sorting should start and end at field 1. Because I didn't specify an ending field and my locale silently ignores commas in numbers it wasn't comparing the numbers I thought it was comparing.