# Sorting .csv from command line

Tags: shell, csv, sorting, unix

I'm trying to sort this line (2010 census block population densities for the whole US) by the last column.

```
12001,2,1009,Alachua FL,29.65612,-82.327274,0.0005131,0.013289229,12,902.9869232
```

**`censusBlockDensities.csv`** (moved here from comment)

```
17001,1,1010,Adams IL,39.960197,-91.373363,0.08861,00.037495258,23,613.41090336
17001,1,1020,Adams IL,39.955861,-91.354113,0.19038,0.493081936,2,4.05612100686
17001,1,1031,Adams IL,39.956978,-91.369,0.002268,0.005874093,0,0,22.8543955664
17001,1,1041,Adams IL,39.94333,-91.345319,0.000358,0.0009236128,0,0480.4506562
17001,1,1051,Adams IL,39.948201,-91.352052,0.213797,0.553731688,64,115.5794427
```

Comment: Great! Was there anything you tried? What shell are you using? Is it a UNIX or a Windows command-line?

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming a unix shell (i.e., bash).

Read the manual page for the sort command:
[`man sort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html)

From the man page:

> The locale specified by the environment affects sort order. Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values.

`export LC_ALL=C`

`sort -t , -k 10,10 -n censusBlockDensities.csv`

Explanation of the flags:

`-t ,`: Specifies commas as field delimiters.

`-k 10,10`: Specifies sorting on the 10th field only (start,stop) (the first field is 1, not 0).

> KEYDEF is F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position, where F is a field number and C a character position in the field; both are origin 1, and the stop position defaults to the line's end. If neither -t nor
>   -b is in effect, characters in a field are counted from the beginning of the preceding whitespace. OPTS is one or more single-letter ordering options [bdfgiMhnRrV], which override global ordering options for that key. If no key is given, use the entire line as the key.

`-n`: Perform a numeric sort instead of the default alphanumeric sort (alternatively, add the 'n' to the `-k` parameter as mention in a comment below).

**`censusBlockDensities.csv`**

```
17001,1,1010,Adams IL,39.960197,-91.373363,0.08861,00.037495258,23,613.41090336
17001,1,1020,Adams IL,39.955861,-91.354113,0.19038,0.493081936,2,4.05612100686
17001,1,1031,Adams IL,39.956978,-91.369,0.002268,0.005874093,0,0,22.8543955664
17001,1,1041,Adams IL,39.94333,-91.345319,0.000358,0.0009236128,0,0480.4506562
17001,1,1051,Adams IL,39.948201,-91.352052,0.213797,0.553731688,64,115.5794427
```

**output:**

```
17001,1,1020,Adams IL,39.955861,-91.354113,0.19038,0.493081936,2,4.05612100686
17001,1,1031,Adams IL,39.956978,-91.369,0.002268,0.005874093,0,0,22.8543955664
17001,1,1051,Adams IL,39.948201,-91.352052,0.213797,0.553731688,64,115.5794427
17001,1,1041,Adams IL,39.94333,-91.345319,0.000358,0.0009236128,0,0480.4506562
17001,1,1010,Adams IL,39.960197,-91.373363,0.08861,00.037495258,23,613.41090336
```

**Edit:** A helpful comment indicated an error in my answer. You also need the `-n` flag to perform a numeric sort (default is alphanumeric). I've amended my answer to include that. You can verify that it is working properly by also trying out the `-r` flag to sort in reverse order. I also added the stop field index to the `-k 10` parameter, as mentioned in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13868242/2074605).

Additionally, you should check your input file to make sure you have the same number of fields in each line:

`awk '{print gsub(/,/,"")}' censusBlockDensities.csv`

```
9
9
10 <-- the third record has an additional field
9
9
```

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work. Note that this is a .csv that I manipulated in Excel then exported as a .csv again

`export LC_ALL=C`

`sort -t , -k 10 censusBlockDensities.csv > 2.csv`

output:
`17001,1,1010,Adams IL,39.960197,-91.373363,0.08861,00.037495258,23,613.41090336
17001,1,1020,Adams IL,39.955861,-91.354113,0.19038,0.493081936,2,4.05612100686
17001,1,1031,Adams IL,39.956978,-91.369,0.002268,0.005874093,0,0,22.8543955664
17001,1,1041,Adams IL,39.94333,-91.345319,0.000358,0.0009236128,0,0480.4506562
17001,1,1051,Adams IL,39.948201,-91.352052,0.213797,0.553731688,64,115.5794427`

Comment: `sort -n -t , -k 10` or `sort -t , -k 10n` - the 'n' for numeric sort

Comment: @user3502552 The first thing I noticed about your new sample data was that you have an additional field in the third row. See my updated answer for a way to detect those.